# Program to Replace a string of one or more blanks with a single blank. No library functions can be used. This is not EOF version

Tags: c

```
/*   ============================================================================
     Name        : 3_1-9.c
     Author      : Arvind Bakshi
     Version     :
     Copyright   : AbcoolCoding
     Description : Program to Replace a string of one or more blanks with a single blank
     ============================================================================
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define NOBLANK 'a'
int main(void) {
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);
    char string[30],out[30];
    int i;
    puts("Enter a String of size < 30");
    fgets(string,sizeof(string),stdin);
    for(i=0; string[i]; i++){
        if(string[i]!=' ')
            out[i]=string[i];
    }
    puts(out);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The above program fails to shrink down more than one blanks in a string. Note that no library functions except stdio.h are allowed. You can find the code at -https://github.com/abcool/C_training/blob/Chapter-1/01_1.5.3_1-9.c
[image: Output of the above code when run on codechef.com/ide]

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my observation from the code you mentioned, **firstly** here

```
fgets(string,sizeof(string),stdin);
```

`fgets()` stored the `\n` char at end of buffer if read. From the manual page of `fgets()`

> **fgets()** reads in at most one less than size characters from stream  and
>          stores  them  into  the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an
>          EOF or a newline.  If a **newline is read**, it is **stored into the  buffer**.

you need to remove the trailing `\n` char. One way is to use `strcspn()`. For e.g

```
string[strcspn(string, "\n")] = 0;
```

**Secondly**, here

```
out[i]=string[i];
```

for `out` array you should use different index rather than `i`. For e.g

```
int count = 0;
for(i=0; string[i]; i++){
   if(string[i]!=' ')
      out[count++]=string[i]; /* use count for out */
}
```

And then put the `\0` char at the end of `out`.

```
out[count] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0; string[i]; i++){
    if(string[i]!=' ')
        out[i]=string[i];
}
```

Because *out* can be smaller than *string* you need to have a separate index for each, the index in *out* must progress only when you put a new character in it

So currently you print non initialized characters, that explains the '+' and probably a null character just after stopping the print.

*Replace a string of one or more blanks with a single blank* : your program *try* to remove all the spaces, not to replace consecutive spaces by only one

Do not forget to put the ending null char in *out* at the end

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);
    char string[30],out[30];
    int i,j=0;
    puts("Enter a String of size < 30");
    fgets(string,sizeof(string),stdin);
    for(i=0; string[i]; i++){
        if(string[i]!=' ' || string[i]=='\n'){
            out[j]=string[i];
            j++;
        }
        else if(string[i]==' ' && string[i+1]!=' '){
        out[j]=string[i];
        j++;
        }
    }
    puts(out);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Comment: How about this?

Comment: This works on single lines but unable to work on sentences across multiple lines. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ArvindBakshi you have to add `out[j] = 0;` after the _for_ to finish the out string. Remember _fgets_ read one line. If you want to manage multi lines you have first to decide what to do with a sequence of \n, to simplify it or to keep it unmodified ?

Comment: I want to keep \n as it is. Only blank spaces i.e. '  ' needs to be shrinked.

Comment: I have written the code for \n also. Please see.